# EntityFramework - using the project context in a static class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've started to work with EntityFramework and I created a model of users.
I would like to have a custom static class that I'll use to store the related functions of the users and I was wondering what would be the best practice for it.
I tried to read a bit and I found couple of options:

1. Create the static class and pass the project context as a parameter for each function:

```
internal static User? Get(ProjectContext context, uint id) =>
        context.Get<User>(i => i.Id == id);
```

2. Create the users class as non static and pass the context in the constructor:

```
private ProjectContext _context;
internal Users(ProjectContext context) =>
        _context = context;
```

3. Adding the functions directly to the context's class (but this will make the class extremely heavy when I'll have many models)
4. Initialize a new context object in the functions:

```
internal static User? Get(uint id) =>
        new ProjectContext().Get<User>(i => i.Id == id);
```

What would be the best way to deal with this issue?
I believe that the best way can also be a different option from what I've listed and I'm open minded to hear.

Thanks,
Noy.

I've tried the options listed below and they worked but I would like to know the best practice way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have researched a bit further and found out that what I'm looking for is a service with DI as mentioned, this is my code and it works exactly how I wanted it to:

When starting the server:
`Users` is the service class

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ProjectContext>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<Users>();
```

Users.cs:

```
private readonly ProjectContext _context;
public Users(ProjectContext context) =>
    _context = context;

/// <summary>
/// Gets a user by it's id.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">Id of the user to get.</param>
/// <returns>User of given id or null if not found.</returns>
internal User? Get(uint id) =>
    _context.Get<User>(i => i.Id == id);
```

in the controller:

```
private readonly Users _users;
public UsersController(Users users) =>
    _users = users;
```

Comment: Looks good. I'd only rename `Users` to `UserService`.

Answer (score 0):

The most idiomatic approach in modern .NET is using [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), so in case you will be starting a new relatively big project the best approach would be the second one since it enables usage of the DI. It can be combined with the first one, though I would recommend using [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```
internal static UserExts
{
     internal static User? GetUser(this ProjectContext context, uint id) =>
        context.Get<User>(i => i.Id == id);
}
```

Which allows usage like `_ctx.GetUser(1)` (though I would not expose such simple method as extension one);

For test/throw away project any approach which will require less ceremony is fine.

Also I would recommend to investigate different design/architecture patterns which will allow you to make more suitable choices for your case (for example there are some [Microsoft guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/)).

Read more:

- [Repository pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-design) - quite often is used, but note that EF itself is already a Repository + Unit of Work
- [Specification pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) - can be quite useful if you decide to abstract over EF, with some existing [implementations](https://github.com/ardalis/Specification)
- [CQRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs)

Comment: Do I really want to make an extension function for every database action? When having multiple models it will be dozens of functions

Comment: @NoyBueno no. Again, it depends on use case. Usually I use extension methods to encapsulate some complex common functionality.